# Why is publish_stream not listed in extended permissions reference?

Tags: facebook, permissions, publish

I was wondering why is there no `publish_stream` permission on [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/) or any [other](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions) permission reference pages.

Is it a documentation bug or something fishy going on? It's still mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/#comments) and [there](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/), but not in any of the overviews (which seem to refer only to `publish_actions` permission). What's the deal?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like they were phasing this permission out, but didn't update their documentation for some time. Now it states the following:

> Facebook used to have a permission called publish_stream.
>   publish_actions replaces it in all cases. This permission also
>   replaces photo_upload.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-extended-publish

Comment: In my app, the permission did not really show up - means , the Facebook Pop up did not ask for the permission. I was using publish_stream, when I changed it to publish_actions it worked as expected.

Comment: Great! I fixed it now and it works! If all problems would be so easy to fix :))

Answer (score 5):

I believe it has been replaced with publish_actions.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/04/25/streamlining-publish_stream-and-publish_actions-permissions/

Comment: As I understand it, `publish_stream` is not deprecated - as it appears to grant permissions for a wider scope of actions and is in fact even mentioned in July 10 (2013) breaking changes. It seems to be a perfectly valid extended permission that is omitted from any reference and shows up only in examples. I find it strange that a more general permission does not have a more explicit description in the API docs.

Comment: Not anymore. The `publish_stream` stopped working for me today morning (5/6/2015)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's been deprecated, just a recommended permission. If you want to publish on friend's timeline, you still need publish_stream.