# Login Permission not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, permissions, facebook-javascript-sdk

- I am use `Javascript SDK` script for the `FB` log-in and with this log-in i want to use the users public own shared post.
- For that reason i use below `javascript` code:

  ```
  FB.login(function(response)
              {
                  if (response.authResponse)
                  {
                      console.log('Welcome!');
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      console.log('User cancelled login');
                  }
              }, {scope:'publish_stream'});
  ```
- In above code i'll gives `scope:'publish_stream'` but when any user login that time only get permission about `profile_info` then what was the problem that i dont understand so please help me
- Basically i'll gives `scope` so when user login that time must ask but in my case its behaviour is not normal ill put image below of the user login permission page.
  [image]
- Please guide what i change in code or if any other way then also provide me,Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Facebook developers page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.3#login), this is the way to do it:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // Logged into your app and Facebook.
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
  } else {
    // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
    // they are logged into this app or not.
  }
});
```

Or you could check the login status with:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
});
```

**Update 1:** Here you can see a [full list](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions) with all the permissions you can set in the scope.

You can see you need to use `read_stream` and not `publish_stream` I think that is your problem.

**Update 2:** I found this ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23633717/2932698)):

> Facebook used to have a permission called publish_stream. publish_actions replaces it in all cases. This permission also replaces photo_upload.

So you might as well use `publish_actions` instead of `publish_stream` since it is deprecated now.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-extended-publish

I hope this helped you further

Comment: I don't have problem with the login but i actually problem with the user permission.

Comment: @Virbhadrasinh then what is your question/problem? Because it's not really clear what the problem is.

Comment: My Question is very much clear and that is simple >> if i give the "scope" of read_stream into JS code and when user login through my website app it will only ask about basic profile information permission not about the read stream and also my code can not fetch the stream data

Comment: @Virbhadrasinh I updated my answer. I think you need to use `read_stram` instead of `publish_stream` (see the permissions page I linked)

Comment: Sorry @Bram sir but any of the permission if i put into the `scope` but it will only display the as same as screen that provide in Question.

Comment: @Virbhadrasinh and if you add `auth_type: 'rerequest'`  behind the scope?